# Chrome Extension: accessing the DOM of the popup.html AND getting jQuery to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Chrome Extension, but I am stuck with two problems (keep in mind that I am an absolute beginner when it comes to building Chrome Extensions):

1. I want to access the DOM of the popup.html file (which is the basis of my extension). I have tried doing this using script directly inside popup.html but I get a warning from Chrome saying that inline script is unsafe. I have tried using an external file in the same way and that also does not work. I have also tried putting the code in a background script file as well as a content script file.
2. Secondly, I want to use jQuery on to access my popup.html page and it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action":
        {
            "default_icon": "icon.png",
            "default_title": "Testing.",
            "default_popup": "popup.html"
        },

    "background":
        {
            "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js"],
            "persistent": false             
        },

    "content_scripts": 
        [
            {
              "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
               "js": ["content.js"]                 
            }
        ]       
}
```

Here is my popup.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
     <link type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
      <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="top_bar"> NAV BAR</div>    
      </div>          
    </body>
  </html>
```

In order to test all this, I have been trying to access the `div` navigation bar and simply display its contents, but the alert always displays `null`. When using jQuery, the alert does not even come up.

This is the JavaScript I use:

```
var div = document.getElementById("top_bar");
alert(div.innerHTML);
```

I would really appreciate some help with this, as well as an explanation as to where to proper place would be to put code for accessing the DOM of the popup.html page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It's almost always a bad idea to use the same script as background and popup script, unless it's a common utility library. Don't mix them up.

2) Your JS gets executed BEFORE any of the `<body>` is constructed. You should wrap it in some DOM ready event. Since you're using jQuery, this will do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var div = document.getElementById("top_bar");
  alert(div.innerHTML);
});
```

3) Don't use alerts in popups. It can make the popup lose focus, which will lead to it being destroyed.  For debug, use standard `console.log()` facilities.

4) ..and to see the console and errors from the popup, right-click the browser action button you have and select "Inspect popup".

Comment: Please could you clarify your first point. I'm still not quite sure where I should put code for the DOM of the extension.

Comment: Certainly. The background page and the popup page are completely different documents - therefore it's a bit strange to use exactly the same script. Note that you have an Event page, even, not simply a background page (persistent = false), which makes it even more special. Read the docs to learn more. And the popup page is created when you open the popup and destroyed when it loses focus.